# Loading null values into Primitive types

Tags: android, ormlite

I am trying to load a database row into a DO object using ormlite query methods. The problem I am facing is with the null values in the database which are mapped to a Wrapper type field in the DO object. The null fields are populated into the DO as 0 which messes up my business logic.

Is there any way possible to cause ormlite to populate these fields as null instead of 0.

My sample DO structure:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="PERSON")
public class Person
{
   @DatabaseField(columnName="NAME", dataType=DataType.STRING, useGetSet=true)
   private String name;

   @DatabaseField(columnName = "AGE", dataType = DataType.SHORT, useGetSet = true)
   private Short age;

   public String getName() 
   {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) 
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public Short getAge() 
   {
     return age;
   }

   public void setAge(Short age) 
   {
     this.age = age;
   }
}
```

The DAO code that I am using to load the objects is:

```
person = queryForEq("NAME", someName).get(0);
```

To summarise, in the Person class, if the age of person is stored as null in the SQLite database, ormlite is populating as 0 on querying the object. I want to avoid this and ensure the age is set as null. Is there any way to acheive this?

Comment: I'm curious why you use the `useGetSet` instead of letting it use reflection?

Comment: I have no specific reason for using `useGetSet`. Was trying it out. Will using `useGetSet` have any negative impact on performance of my application?

Comment: No, just that it is not the default and I was curious.  Reflection is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right thing to do here is to not specify the `dataType` as part of your `@DatabaseField` annotation.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) will then properly use the `DataType.SHORT_OBJ` field type.  Since you are overriding the default field type and saying that the `Short` field is actually a primitive, if ORMLite *did* assign a null to it, it would cause a NPE so it assigns 0 instead.  Your data object should instead be:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName="NAME", useGetSet=true)
private String name;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "AGE", useGetSet = true)
private Short age;
```

Really you never need to specify the `dataType` unless you are overriding something or if ORMLite can't make a good automatic type determination (ex: `byte[]`).